# jQuery slide a DIV out when scroll to anchor tag ~

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to slide a DIV with contents out -- within a defined page area; within a long vertical 1 page website.

I have it setup with 6 DIV blocks;

Block 5 I have a CSS3 / jQuery animation wrapped in a DIV -- that I would like to *SLIDE* out into the page (from either left or right) with jQuery.

I'm thinking determining the point of slide from a defined anchor point; put within the the mark-up of the area that I'd like the DIV to slide into.

How could I write this;

..something like -- if anchor tag; SlideIn?

Something like;

```
  slideLeftHide: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Have a look at animate() http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/SZ8uH/2/

Try something like this:

```
var animInTriggeredAt = $("a#slidein").offset().top; //show when the anchor comes on stage
var animOutTriggeredAt = animInTriggeredAt + $(window).height(); //hide when it leaves the stage
var animActive = false;

// handle scroll event
$(window).scroll(checkScrollCues);

function checkScrollCues(){
    var scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollY > animInTriggeredAt && scrollY < animOutTriggeredAt && !animActive){
        animActive = true;
        $("#myAnimatedDiv").show(); //put whatever animation code you want in here
    } else if ((scrollY < animInTriggeredAt || scrollY > animOutTriggeredAt) && animActive){
         animActive = false;
        $("#myAnimatedDiv").hide(); //put whatever animation code you want in here
    }
}
```